# Android listview update data when scroll view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have 1 listView, items of listivew about : button translate, text translate.
when i click button translate,text translate success,(save object model). But error no change text had translate when scroll.I want save status click button translate when scroll again, it translate. can you help me? sorry my english.
Code : I remove code. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I want to clarify your issue:

- you want `tvTipsMessage` update with translated text.
- your code works when click in `btnDrunkenTranslate` but when you scroll down then scroll up again, `tvTipsMessage` display the untranslate text?

If those above is correct, then I think your problem is you aren't save the new translated text to your object model (although you said you do).

Your object model is `FSTipModel`, and you use `item.getText()` to get the display text. But from your posted code, I don't find any code update that value.
You may need to apply this:

- add `FSTipModel mItem;` in `ViewHolder`
- in `ViewHolder.fillData`, add `mItem = item;`
- in `onTranslateTipSuccess`, replace `tvTipsMessage.setText(CommonUtil.getStringData(data.getResult()));` 
   by

  `mItem.setText(data.getResult());
  mText = mItem.getText();
  tvTipsMessage.setText(CommonUtil.getStringData(mText));`

Hope this works.